# Check whether a string is not equal to any of a list of strings

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way to convert some code like this:

```
If someString <> "02" And someString <> "03" And someString <> "06" And someString <> "07" Then
     btnButton.Enabled = False
End If
```

kinda into something like this (multiple values for one variable)

```
If someString <> "02", "03", "06", "07" Then
     btnButton.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: In C#, you could do `if (!(new [] {"02", "03", "06", "07"}).Contains(someString)) { ..` - but I don't speak VB.Net

Comment: Are the various strings in an Array? @Blorgbeard Yeah that's what I was trying to get to.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: `If Not {"02", "03", "06", "07"}.Contains(someString) Then`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Would [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb910499%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) work?

```
Dim testAgainst As String() = {"02","03","06","07"}
If Not testAgainst.Contains(someString) Then
    btnButton.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: Nitpick: it’s not `Array.Contains` but rather a LINQ extension to `IEnumerable(Of String)`. =)

Comment: Use a hashset instead of an array, even for small arrays if you are using the code in a tight loop it can make a large difference.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I would just assume, with the `btnButton.Enabled = False`, that it isn’t a tight loop =) In which case constructing the `HashSet` from the array is still slower. But in other cases, good point.

Comment: The construction would be a one time cost as you should make it static and not create it inline in the code. HashSets are thread safe if you are only doing read operations.

Answer (score 15):

You can (ab)use `Select` for this in simple cases:

```
Select Case someString
    Case "02", "03", "06", "07"
    Case Else
        btnButton.Enabled = False
End Select
```

Also, a common extension that I use is:

```
<Extension()>
Function [In](Of TItem, TColl)(this As TItem, ParamArray items() As TColl)
    Return Array.IndexOf(items, this) > -1
End Function
```

So:

```
If Not someString.In("02", "03", "06", "07") Then
    btnButton.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: +1 for Select Case abuse. Even though it's somewhat obvious, I did not realize you could use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

```
Dim invalidvalues As New List(Of String) From { _
    "02", _
    "03,", _
    "04", _
    "07" _
}

If invalidvalues.Contains(x) Then
    btnButton.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: And note that you can make it look nicer by omitting the `_`s in VB 2010 and later.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions    

btnButton.Enabled = Regex.IsMatch(someString, "^0[2367]$")
```