# Multiple Strings in One String with Or

Tags: vb.net, string, boolean

I want to check every string in **indexpage** string witf If. This is **indexpage**

```
Dim indexpage As String = "string1" Or "string2"
```

I've tryed parentheses, OrElse but it didn't worked.. And It's not a problem about If function. It still gives me this error when I try it without If function...

The Error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "string1" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.
```

Comment: What would you expect `indexpage` to contain after such an assignment?

Comment: Or are you saying you want to check if `indexpage` is already equal to either one of those strings?

Comment: In that case: possible duplicate of [Check whether a string is not equal to any of a list of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725039/check-whether-a-string-is-not-equal-to-any-of-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: Oops - that one is if it's **not** in the list of strings - your Q is the same but without the Not.

Comment: You'll need an [if statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx).

Comment: Thank you @JamesThorpe! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to James Thorpe, I found the answer.

```
Dim testAgainst As String() = {"02","03","06","07"}
```

And the If function

```
    If testAgainst.Contains(WebControl1.Source.ToString) Then
        ' code
    Else
        ' code
    End If
```