# Simple if check for multiple values vb

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

In Sql we can filter like
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName IN ("firstValue", "secondValue")

How to check in VB.Net, is there a simple way to do it? 
or, is it just

```
If variable = "firstValue" Or variable = "secondValue"
    'Code Here
End If
```

Comment: `Case, If, OrElse` are a few you can use, pick one...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether a string is not equal to any of a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725039/check-whether-a-string-is-not-equal-to-any-of-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 5):

Your code isn’t valid: you need to compare the values explicitly:

```
If variable = "firstValue" OrElse variable = "secondValue" Then
```

(`OrElse` is similar to `Or` but it’s preferred because it stops evaluating subsequent comparisons once it has found one that fits, because then, regardless of the remaining comparisons, the end result would always be `True`.)

If this becomes too tedious, you can put your values into a collection and check whether your test value is contained in them:

```
Dim values As New List(Of String) From {"firstValue", "secondValue"}

If values.Contains(variable) Then …
```

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't cover if there are multiple values like lets say > 5 values

Comment: @Rahul Except it does.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, could do this with a Case statement.

```
Select Case variable
   Case "firstValue","secondValue"
      'code here
End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a very old question, but it can be done like this:

```
    {"firstValue", "secondValue"}.contains(Variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at say a datatable you could do the below...

```
dim myvar as string() = ""

For Each dr As DataRow In Table1.Rows             
         if dr("TABLE1_COLUMNNAME").toString = "Something" then 
         myvar = dr("TABLE1_COLUMNNAME").toString  
         end if
 Next
```