# Equals() function with multiple values instead of one

Tags: vb.net

I have been using the following since a few years:

```
Dim mycol = xml.First(Function(x) CStr(x.Attribute("name")).Equals("Source"))
```

Now I would like to retrieve if either the name attribute is equal to `"Source"` or `"Input"`.

Does any solution exist for this case?

I have tried the following without any success

```
Dim cases As String() = {"Source", "Input"}
Dim mycol = xml.First(Function(x) CStr(x.Attribute("name")).Equals(cases))
```

Comment: You could use something like `{"Source", "Input"}.Contains(CStr(x.Attribute("name"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether a string is not equal to any of a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725039/check-whether-a-string-is-not-equal-to-any-of-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple if check for multiple values vb](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38726396/11683)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would reverse the order of the comparison and use `Contains`:

```vb
Dim mycol = xml.First(Function(x) cases.Contains(CStr(x.Attribute("name"))))
```